# Need to save Array data to Database, from a Web Form, utilizing Stored Procedure, in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, database, stored-procedures

I am not able to figure-out on my own how to save a Web Form Array Data Set to a User's record, utilizing C# and SQL Stored Procedure.  I was able to parse the User's information and save it to the database just fine.  However, when I reached the part to save the User's selected data to the database, I ran into a wall and can't seem to find my way out.  Can someone please guide me through this maze?

Here is the set of data that I am providing to the User for selection that I need to save once the user has made the required choices:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate addsection"></span>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control" id="ProductCode1" name="ProductCode[]" style="border-bottom-color:black!important;border-color:white;">
                        <option selected>Select Product</option>
                        <option value='292' data-description='APRIL Afternoon At the Greenhouse TICKET' data-price='35.00'>AAATG</option>
                        <option value='285' data-description='APRIL AFTERNOON AT THE GREENHOUSE Ticket EARLYBIRD SPECIAL' data-price='30.00'>AAATGearlybird</option>
                        <option value='30' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1/2 Lb' data-price='4.25'>AB12LB</option>
                        <option value='31' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1/4 Lb' data-price='2.25'>AB14LB</option>
                        <option value='29' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1 Lb' data-price='8.00'>AB1LB</option>
                        <option value='47' data-description='Organic Adzuki Seeds 1 Lb' data-price='5.00'>ABS1LB</option>
                        <option value='145' data-description='Alberto&#x27;s Lemon/Garlic Salad Dressing 16 Oz.' data-price='11.00'>Alberto&#x27;s Dressing</option>
                        <option value='241' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 4 oz.' data-price='2.00'>APRIL</option>
                        <option value='310' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 16 oz' data-price='7.75'>April16oz</option>
                        <option value='309' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 8 oz' data-price='4.00'>April8oz</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <td style="width:70%;"><input id="ProductDesc1" name="ProductDesc[]" class="form-control" style="width: 100%; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white;"  type="text" value="" /></td>
            <td><input id="quantity1" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" style="width: 50px; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white; text-align: center;"  type="text" value="0" placeholder="1" /></td>
            <td>
                <input id="ProductPrice1" name="ProductPrice[]" class="form-control cost" style="width: 95px; text-align: center; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white;"  type="text" value="" placeholder="$0.00" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eject remove"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate addsection"></span>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control" id="ProductCode2" name="ProductCode[]" style="border-bottom-color:black!important;border-color:white;">
                        <option selected>Select Product</option>
                        <option value='292' data-description='APRIL Afternoon At the Greenhouse TICKET' data-price='35.00'>AAATG</option>
                        <option value='285' data-description='APRIL AFTERNOON AT THE GREENHOUSE Ticket EARLYBIRD SPECIAL' data-price='30.00'>AAATGearlybird</option>
                        <option value='30' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1/2 Lb' data-price='4.25'>AB12LB</option>
                        <option value='31' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1/4 Lb' data-price='2.25'>AB14LB</option>
                        <option value='29' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1 Lb' data-price='8.00'>AB1LB</option>
                        <option value='47' data-description='Organic Adzuki Seeds 1 Lb' data-price='5.00'>ABS1LB</option>
                        <option value='145' data-description='Alberto&#x27;s Lemon/Garlic Salad Dressing 16 Oz.' data-price='11.00'>Alberto&#x27;s Dressing</option>
                        <option value='241' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 4 oz.' data-price='2.00'>APRIL</option>
                        <option value='310' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 16 oz' data-price='7.75'>April16oz</option>
                        <option value='309' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 8 oz' data-price='4.00'>April8oz</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <td style="width:70%;"><input id="ProductDesc2" name="ProductDesc[]" class="form-control" style="width: 100%; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white;"  type="text" value="" /></td>
            <td><input id="quantity2" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" style="width: 50px; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white; text-align: center;"  type="text" value="0" placeholder="1" /></td>
            <td>
                <input id="ProductPrice2" name="ProductPrice[]" class="form-control cost" style="width: 95px; text-align: center; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white;"  type="text" value="" placeholder="$0.00" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eject remove"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate addsection"></span>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control" id="ProductCode3" name="ProductCode[]" style="border-bottom-color:black!important;border-color:white;">
                        <option selected>Select Product</option>
                        <option value='292' data-description='APRIL Afternoon At the Greenhouse TICKET' data-price='35.00'>AAATG</option>
                        <option value='285' data-description='APRIL AFTERNOON AT THE GREENHOUSE Ticket EARLYBIRD SPECIAL' data-price='30.00'>AAATGearlybird</option>
                        <option value='30' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1/2 Lb' data-price='4.25'>AB12LB</option>
                        <option value='31' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1/4 Lb' data-price='2.25'>AB14LB</option>
                        <option value='29' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1 Lb' data-price='8.00'>AB1LB</option>
                        <option value='47' data-description='Organic Adzuki Seeds 1 Lb' data-price='5.00'>ABS1LB</option>
                        <option value='145' data-description='Alberto&#x27;s Lemon/Garlic Salad Dressing 16 Oz.' data-price='11.00'>Alberto&#x27;s Dressing</option>
                        <option value='241' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 4 oz.' data-price='2.00'>APRIL</option>
                        <option value='310' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 16 oz' data-price='7.75'>April16oz</option>
                        <option value='309' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 8 oz' data-price='4.00'>April8oz</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <td style="width:70%;"><input id="ProductDesc3" name="ProductDesc[]" class="form-control" style="width: 100%; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white;"  type="text" value="" /></td>
            <td><input id="quantity3" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" style="width: 50px; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white; text-align: center;"  type="text" value="0" placeholder="1" /></td>
            <td>
                <input id="ProductPrice3" name="ProductPrice[]" class="form-control cost" style="width: 95px; text-align: center; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white;"  type="text" value="" placeholder="$0.00" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eject remove"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is my Stored Procedure, which has the unique Invoice ID to relate this set to the other data on a separate table:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      JS
-- Create date: Today
-- Description: Save User's choices to database
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InvoiceLineItems] @Quantity float, @UnitPrice float, @Description nvarchar(255), @LineTotal money, @LineItemCodeID int, @InvoiceID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    --- SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ULSInvoiceLineItems] (Quantity, UnitPrice, Description, LineTotal, LineItemCodeID, InvoiceID) 
VALUES (@Quantity, @UnitPrice, @Description, @LineTotal, @LineItemCodeID, @InvoiceID)

END
```

Then, I created a class for the array:

```
    public  class UlsinvoiceLineItems
    {
        public UlsinvoiceLineItems() {}

        public UlsinvoiceLineItems(double Quantity, double UnitPrice, string Description, decimal LineTotal, int LineItemCodeID, int InvoiceID)
        {
            this.Quantity = Quantity;
            this.UnitPrice = UnitPrice;
            this.Description = Description;
            this.LineTotal = LineTotal;
            this.LineItemCodeID = LineItemCodeID;
            this.InvoiceID = InvoiceID;
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public double? Quantity { get; set; }
        public double? UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal? LineTotal { get; set; }
        public int? LineItemCodeID { get; set; }
        public int? InvoiceID { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally, I reached the section where I actually gather the data from the form and upload it to the database, and I am not having any light at all.  This is what I have so far.  What am I missing to reach a successful database upload?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Invoice()
    {
        var result = 0;
        if (HttpContext.Request.Form["Submit"].ToString() == "submit")
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CON__DC")))
            {

                try
                {

                    string[] Quantity = HttpContext.Request.Form["quantity"];
                    string[] ProductPrice = HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductPrice"];
                    string[] ProductDesc = HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductDesc"];
                    string[] ProductCode = HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductCode"];

                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("sp_InvoiceLineItems", connection);
                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Quantity);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", ProductPrice);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", ProductDesc);
                        //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineTotal", ulinv.ProdTotal);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineItemCodeID", ProductCode);
                        //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceID", ulinv.InvoiceNumber);

                        result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    ViewBag.Result($"Database insert failed with: {result}");
                    return View();
                }
                finally
                {
                    // close the Sql Connection
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The code compiles with what I have done so far:
[image]

This is what the whole project looks like right now.  The section marked in RED is what I the focus of my question.

[image: Array Section that needs to be saved to the Database]

UPDATE:

Made a small step forward.  I am now able to get the data from the Text Boxes when I setup the reader like this:

```
                try
                {
                    string description = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductDesc[]"]);
                    lItems.Description = description;

                    double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(HttpContext.Request.Form["quantity[]"]);
                    lItems.Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(Quantity);

                    string UnitPrice = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductPrice[]"]);
                    lItems.UnitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(UnitPrice);

                    string LineItemCodeID = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductCode[]"]);
                    lItems.LineItemCodeID = Convert.ToInt16(LineItemCodeID);

                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("sp_InvoiceLineItems", connection);
                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", lItems.Quantity);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", lItems.UnitPrice);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", lItems.Description);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineTotal", ulinv.ProdTotal);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineItemCodeID", lItems.LineItemCodeID);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceID", ulinv.InvoiceNumber);

                    result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (InvalidCastException e)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    ViewBag.Result($"Database insert failed with: {e}");
                    return View();
                }
                finally
                {
                    // close the Sql Connection
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

I am now reading the first and only record.  If I try to add another row, then I can read the Description filed witch contains both records description, separated by a comma, however, the type double fields fail (rejected for malformed content).

Can anyone please help me to structure the reader to parse through the array and supply the parameters with unique records (one per row)?

Comment: I commend you for actually working directly with SQL as opposed to working with the various ORMs that are available. However, the `SET NOCOUNT ON` directive is not needed in this instance. It could be to your benefit to remove this as it will then return the _Rows Affected_  value from SQL back to the calling command in your ` result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();` line. Of course I'm blind and cant see where _result_ is even defined

Comment: I added the whole constructor for more details.  I hope that helps to define what I have done so far with that specific piece of the project.

Comment: @Mad Myche, Would you be able to recommend one of these ORMs?  Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: I cannot fore I do not use any. I have my own library of data interfaces and I only install what is needed for any particular solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with

**C#**

```
string[] Quantity = HttpContext.Request.Form["quantity"];
string[] ProductPrice = HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductPrice"];
string[] ProductDesc = HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductDesc"];
string[] ProductCode = HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductCode"];
```

HttpContext.Request.Form is a `NameValueCollection` (reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb(v=vs.110).aspx)), therefore, when accessing any value in side the collection, the result will be a `string` not a `string[]`. Your project shouldn't even be compiling in that block of code.

**Question**

**IS YOUR CODE EVEN COMPILING?**

Comment: Yes, it compiles with what I have done so far and I made some adjustments from the comments that I received so far.  The HttpContext.Request.Form  is working to save User Data from a portion  of my project.  So I thought that I would build on it.